# Unity Error ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

When I import a custom package into Unity and trying to build it I get the following error:

IOException: Win32 IO returned ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE. Path: C:\Users...\New Unity Project (3)[Unknown]
System.IO.FileStream.FlushBuffer (System.IO.Stream st) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:1040)
System.IO.FileStream.FlushBuffer () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:1054)
System.IO.FileStream.Flush () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:859)
System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StreamWriter.cs:191)
System.IO.StreamWriter.Dispose (Boolean disposing) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StreamWriter.cs:162)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. I reinstalled Unity and everything worked as it was supposed to.